# Why do type(x) and print(type(x) display slightly different results in python?

Tags: python, types

Let

```
x = [1,2,3]
```

Then in *ipython*, I get the following

```
> In [8]: type(x) 
Out[8]: list
> 
> In [9]: print(type(x)) 
<class 'list'>
```

Why doesn't  `print(type(x))`  just print list, instead of the extra class stuff?

A related question is, how can I display the output

```
type of x is; list
```

`print(' type of x is: ', type(x))`  doesn't do it because I get the extra class stuff, as in

```
In [2]: print(' type of x is: ', type(x))
 type of x is:  <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test `type(x)`. It will always output `<class 'list'>`. The reason you get `list` directly is the IPython do extra work for you.

Using `type()` will return type object. Operate it and get type name using `__name__`.

```
print(' type of x is: ', type(x).__name__)
#  type of x is: list
```

Answer (score 1):

As pwxcoo said, this is `Ipython` doing some extra work for you, try it in a normal python shell and it won't show anything unless you explicitly `print()` it.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely do this the way pwxcoo shows. Before I knew __ name __ was an attribute of type, I did it by converting the type to a string and slicing it as such:

```
str(type(x)).split()[1][1:-2]
```

So this is a good reminder that you can run dir(type) and see that __ name __ is an attribute so you don't have to do the ugly stuff I did!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

> class type(object)
>
> With one argument,
>   return the type of an object. The return value is a type object. The
>   isinstance() built-in function is recommended for testing the type of
>   an object.

For getting the name of the class, you can get it by referring to the special attribute `__name__`

```
print(type(x).__name__)
```

You can find more on `__name__` in the docs here: [https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#definition.**name**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__)